# Disposing Scoped RegionManager

Tags: prism

I have a TabControl and I am creating a new scoped region manager for every tabItem which holds the same usercontrol (which has nested regions in it):
regionManager.Regions["TAB_REGION"].Add(theView, null, true);

[I am not assigning any variable to the new scoped regionmanager.
Also, theView is NonShared and is created for each tabItem and contains some regions
Also theView has prism:ClearChildViewsRegionBehavior.ClearChildViews="True"].

1. Is there a collection which holds all region managers created for the application? The one similar to IRegionCollection which holds all regions in the given RegionManager.
   -If yes, how can I access it?
2. When are the scoped regionmanagers destroyed/removed from memory?
3. Can user destroy/remove scoped regionmanagers while application is still running?
4. When I close a tabItem (using a 'X' button), I remove the view using the code:
   regionManager.Regions["TAB_REGION"].Remove(theView).
   I verified that the view is removed from the "TabRegion". Is there a way I can verify that the associated scoped regionmanager is also removed from memory, in case it is supposed to be?

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

Kindly refer to: https://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/445975